# ruby array intersection performance issue

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to make intersection of n-arrays with millions of elements (database ID's).
This code works perfect, but slow (with very big arrays). How can i improve it?

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[4,5,8]].inject([]){|c,v| c = v if c.size==0; c = c&v if c.size>0; c }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby provides an intersection opperator.

May I suggest you try this:

```
> [[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[4,5,8]].reduce{ |accum, arr| accum & arr }
=> [4]
```

**Edit:**

This can be written a little more concise but it suffers from readability.

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[4,5,8]].reduce(:&)
```

Comment: yes. `[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[4,5,8]].reduce{ |accum, arr| accum | arr }`

Comment: You can use without &, just reduce(:&)

Comment: It's not a reduce, it's because of intersection method.

Comment: Correct. It would work the same if you replace `reduce` with `inject` as they are aliases of each other.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this operator? Any links will help

Answer (score 6):

```
[1,2,3,4] & [2,4,6,8] & [4,5,8] #=> [4]
```

The [intersection method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) uses hash so it should be quick.